# The usage of murkiness

Tags: meaning, adjectives, american-english, adverbs

I would like to know if the word "murkiness" in the sentence below is syntactically correct.

> then nothing will remain from him except as a worm creeps in
>   murkiness. His life begins and ends with an utmost sensation that
>   never exceeds the sensitivity of the skin.

Answer (score 1):

The passage that you quote is perfectly correct syntactically. But so, for that matter, is Noam Chomsky's famous sentence:

> Colorless green ideas sleep furiously.

He wrote it to illustrate that statements can be grammatically correct but meaningless. And the question that arises from your passage is what it's about rather than its grammatical structure. I could find no reference to it on the internet.

The passage is steeped in metaphors. Its author clearly never intended it to be transparent but rather to give readers something to think about.

The first part of the quote, which gives rise to your question, appears to suggest that all that will remain of a man's decayed body is the worm that feeds on it in the obscurity of the grave.

It's in the sense of obscurity/darkness that **murkiness** is used here.

The second part I leave to others to decipher - if necessary.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/murkiness

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29504/syntactically-correct-semantically-incorrect-sentence